# Lowest power way to latch power supply after input pulse

Tags: arduino, low-power, latch

*Background*

Right now I have a circuit consisting of a Adafruit Huzzah Feather (ESP8266 board), an ADXL345 accelerometer, and an ATTiny85 (bare chip).  The circuit is powered by a lipo battery plugged in to the huzzah with the ADXL345 and ATTINy being powered by the VBat pin (so they are always powered).

The INT1 (Interrupt 1) pin of the ADXL345 is connected to ATTiny85 and set to fire on ACTIVITY.  The Tiny wakes on the rising interrupt and turns on the ENABLE pin of the Huzzah (enabling the onboard 3V3 regulator and starting the ESP8266).  When the ESP8266 starts, it clears the interrupt from the ADXL345 (the two are connected via I2C) updates an ePaper display connected via SPI. The Huzzah tells Tiny it is done and ready to shutdown by changing the state on a GPIO pin. Tiny senses this, pulls the ENABLE pin low and then puts itself to sleep.
[image: circuit]
The LED flashes for 50ms every 2s just so I know if the Tiny is awake or sleeping.

*Problem*

The problem I am having is that when the Huzzah is disabled and the Tiny is sleeping, the power consumption is still around 900 uA.  Moving the ammeter around, I found that about half of that is current flowing between the sleeping Tiny and disabled huzzah.  The ADXL345 in measurement mode should only consume 23uA.

In the interest of simplifying things, I'd like to replace the Tiny with something simpler and even lower powered.  The three things I've found by googling are:

- Low power latching relay ([like one of these](https://www.mouser.com/Electromechanical/Relays/Low-Signal-Relays-PCB/_/N-5g38))
- Set-Reset latch/bistable flip-flop ([something from here...](https://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Logic-ICs/Latches/))
- TPL5111 Set-reset timer ([Adafruit makes a breakout for it](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tpl5111-reset-enable-timer-breakout/overview))

Seems like the relay would only consume power while switching but may be overkill (I had difficulty finding a small one since I don't need 10A switching).  The watchdog feature of the TPL5111 chip would be a nice-to-have thing in case the ESP locks up but not required.

Can someone with some EE experience weigh in and help this ME figure out the best way to control power via the enable pin given the above information?  I'm also open to other suggestions too.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. There's a schematic tool built into the editor. It's easy to use and would replace several paragraphs of text and make the schema much clearer. If you already have a schematic you can post that but please turn off the grid if making a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Wasn't at my home PC, I'll work something up and edit the post

Comment: Are you using pull up resistors? When you're "asleep", do you pull the GPIO pin high or low?

Comment: The ADXL345 is on a breakout board that has pull ups (I forget the value and will confirm tonight).  I have ordered some samples of the TPL5111 that should come in a few days.  On the Tiny, I was pulling the pins low based on Nick Gammon's research (http://www.gammon.com.au/power).  I wasn't doing anything in particular with the pins of the ESP since its power gets cut.  Should I add external pull up or down resistors on the ESP GPIOs?

Comment: [This](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B06XHHT4T8) is the accelerometer, it has 4.7k pull ups and a [MIC5205](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005785A.pdf) regulator which could account for some of the power draw.

Comment: [Looks like](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/031/354/original/adafruit_products_schem.png?1458433763) the AP2112 voltage regulator on the feather has a 10kΩ pull-up which would be connected to ground when I pull the enable in low accounting for 300-400 uA current draw when shut down.  Per the [AP2112 datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP2112.pdf), EN is pulled down by 3MΩ internally. Could I swap the 10kΩ resistor for a 100kΩ and maintain same functionality but with lower power draw?

Comment: @MattD: You've added a *wiring* diagram instead of a schematic. It's very pretty but tells us nothing about what it's for or how it's supposed to work. You seem to be adding a lot of data in the comments. If it's relevant to the question it should probably be *in* the question but the question is rather long already. I think your best bet is to summarise the question at the top with a schematic of the essential parts. It's rather unusual not to have an answer after two days and it suggests that nobody can understand it.

Comment: @Transistor I don't have a schematic that is very useful right now as Huzzah and accelerometer boards are "black boxes" in my schematic since I imported them as complete parts.  I wasn't planning on digesting those schematics until I was ready to make my own board with just the parts I need.  I did review the [Huzzah schematic](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/031/354/original/adafruit_products_schem.png) and identify a 10kΩ pull-up on the enable pin.  I found it on the board and desoldered it last night and power off current dropped to 3uA.

Comment: The built-in schematic app on the editor toolbar has a custom component that allows you to add as many pins to it as required. You can name the device and each pin.